# cant open (X11?) window on ubuntu

Tags: xorg

I´m trying to open itksnap on an Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance. However, I only get the error msg 'cant open display'. Presumably it is an X11 display. I´ve looked around and checked that x11 forward is set to Yes in ~/.ssh/config and in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

I´ve also tried running xclock with the same error msg.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an X server running on your local system, to which X11 traffic may be forwarded?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. How would I find out / start an X11 server on my local machine?

Comment: You need to be running a graphical environment (X) such as gnome, xfce, kde, etc. You can run a minimal X server, but as you have to ask that may be more complicated. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149066/what-is-x-window-system and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Comment: Thank you so much for the links provided. Now I have a rudimentary understanding and managed to get the X11 windows up and running. However, I received an error msg upon logging in: /usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority does not exist - ...does this matter?

Comment: If you are connecting via ssh , the command is `ssh -X ...` As a general comment it is unlikely you need to forward X to manage a server as most of what you do for server admin is on the command line. If you feel you *must* have a graphical interface use cockpit , webmin, or one of hte many web based interfaces designed for server management.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I think your two comments would make a worthwhile answer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Thank you for the suggestion but I am not sure if the problem is solved.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it. The purpose is not systems maint, but image analysis. Hence the need for X11.